# Second inline Javascript popup not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue. I want to have two inline javascript popups on a web page. Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {
            parentElementID: "target"
        });
    });
    var popup2;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup2 = Sys.create.popup("#popup2", {
            parentElementID: "target"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the content of the page:

```
content
<span id="target" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 40%; margin-top: -125px; margin-left: -200px;"></span>
<div id="popup" style="background: #ff6a00; color: #000; padding: 15px; margin: 0px">
    Popup #1
</div>
<div id="popup2" style="background: #ffd800; color: #000; padding: 15px; margin: 0px">
    Popup #2
</div>
content
<script>Sys.onReady(function () { popup.show(); })</script>
<script>Sys.onReady(function () { popup2.show(); })</script>
```

Both popups target the same location on the page. So I would expect the second one to overlap the first. The first popup is correctly popping up. The second is actually appearing in the page, it isn't popping up at all. As you can see the content on the page is going around it:

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is Sys? What scripts are you referencing to be able to do this?

Comment: I am not referencing any scripts. I am running on an ASP.NET server. Is this the wrong approach for popups? In actuality, I am using ASPNET server controls within the popup div's but it doesn't work for this simple example either...

Comment: Yeah I would look at something more like [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), or if you want to stick to .NET maybe then [AjaxControlToolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)... personally I go with jQuery stuff.